# MikroC, mi PIC no quiere leer los bits en asm

Tags: c, asm

tengo un pequeño problemita con mi programa en MikroC, ya que este si funciona cuando realizo el debuger en este mismo, pero cuando quiero hacerlo en físico solo se queda pasmado y no hace nada.
Ya conecté igualmente el PIC, de manera que este si pueda recibir señales por el puerto A, ya también lo probe igualmente con ensamblador y de igual manera este si funciona, pero ya haciéndolo con MikroC y combinando los dos ya es cuando no funciona y me pidieron que forzosamente cumpliera con los dos.
Aquí les dejo mi código, espero que me puedan ayudar:

```
sbit LCD_RS at LATE0_bit; // for writing to output pin always use latch (PIC18 family)
sbit LCD_EN at LATE1_bit; // for writing to output pin always use latch (PIC18 family)
sbit LCD_D4 at LATC0_bit; // for writing to output pin always use latch (PIC18 family)
sbit LCD_D5 at LATC1_bit; // for writing to output pin always use latch (PIC18 family)
sbit LCD_D6 at LATC6_bit; // for writing to output pin always use latch (PIC18 family)
sbit LCD_D7 at LATC7_bit; // for writing to output pin always use latch (PIC18 family)
sbit LCD_RS_Direction at TRISE0_bit;
sbit LCD_EN_Direction at TRISE1_bit;
sbit LCD_D4_Direction at TRISC0_bit;
sbit LCD_D5_Direction at TRISC1_bit;
sbit LCD_D6_Direction at TRISC6_bit;
sbit LCD_D7_Direction at TRISC7_bit;
// LCD fin del modulo de conexiones
// Variables
unsigned short RESULTADO = 0;
#define BIT_A 0X0C
#define BIT_B 0X0D
#define RES_AND_1 0X0E
#define RES_AND_2 0X0F
void main(void)
{

  OSCCON = 0XFF;
  //LATA = 0; // Escribe ceros
  TRISA = 0X7F;
  TRISB = 0X00;
  TRISE = 0; // Coloca al puerto E como salida
  TRISC = 0;
  Lcd_Init();          // Inicializa LCD
  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR); // Clear display
  Delay_ms(1);
  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF); // Cursor off

  while (1)
  {
    asm {
                MOVF PORTA,W
                ANDLW 00000001
                MOVWF BIT_A
                MOVF PORTA,W
                ANDLW 00000010
                MOVWF BIT_B
                RRNCF BIT_B,1


                COMF BIT_A,W
                ANDLW 00000001
                ANDWF BIT_B,W
                MOVWF RES_AND_1
                COMF BIT_B,W
                ANDLW 00000001
                ANDWF BIT_A,W
                MOVWF RES_AND_2
                IORWF RES_AND_1, W
                MOVWF _RESULTADO
    }
    switch (RESULTADO)
    {
    case (0):
    {
      Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR); // Clear display
      Lcd_Out(1, 1, "El bit esta apagado");
      PORTB.F0 = 0;
      Delay_ms(1000);
      break;
    }
    case (1):
    {
      Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR); // Clear display
      Lcd_Out(1, 1, "El bit esta encendido");
      PORTB.F0 = 1;
      Delay_ms(1000);
      break;
    }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `while (1)` hará que se quede en un bucle infinito, no importa? Estás seguro de que esa es la forma correcta de incluir código ensamblador en el programa? Cada compilador tiene su forma de hacerlo.